# cut+sed function joined

Tags: sed, cut

**Input**

```
dir/foo
```

**Output**

```
dir./
```

so I need:

```
echo 'dir/foo' | MAGIC
```

**Q:** What is `MAGIC`? (something like a `cut`+`sed` joined:D)

Comment: How many slashes will there be in "dir"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options here. My preference would be towards a parameter expansion:

```
foo=dir/foo
echo "${foo%/*}./"
```

Another option is awk:

```
echo "dir/foo" | awk -F/ '{ print $1"./" }'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use also `dirname` with `read`

```
read foo
echo "$(dirname "$foo")./"
```

and `dirname` with `xargs`.

```
echo "$(xargs dirname)./"
```

Example usage with a function:

```
$ MAGIC() { echo "$(xargs dirname)./"; }
$ echo 'dir/foo' | MAGIC
dir./
```

Comment: I think you meant `dirname`.

Comment: @terdon: Oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Another use of `read`

```
IFS=/ read a b <<<"dir/foo"
echo "$a./"
```

Won't work if "dir/foo" is actually "/home/user/foo"

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you really want a literal `.`? This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101).

Anyway, a simple way of doing what you seem to be asking is to use [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname):

```
$ echo $(dirname "dir/foo")./
dir./
```

The main advantages of `dirname` is that it can deal with spaces and is part of GNU coreutils so will be installed in all GNU systems. Also it can deal with arbitrarily long paths:

```
$ echo $(dirname "aa/bb bb/cc/foo")./
aa/bb bb/cc./
```

You can use @EvanTeitelman's trick to make this into a function:

```
$ MAGIC() { echo $(dirname "$1")./; }
$ MAGIC 'dir/foo'
dir./
$ MAGIC 'dir/foo bar/foo'
dir/foo bar./
```